# Simple Perl string match with a special character i.e '

Tags: perl

```
my $var_cot_descn="Veteran's Affairs";
my %cot_descn= ("Correctional","Veteran's Affairs","State Pharmacy Assistance Program","VA Medical Center","VA Mail Order Pharmacy","PHS 340B Entity");

if (exists $cot_descn{$var_cot_descn}){
    print  "CustomerDomain=\"GOV\"
        />
        </Org>
        \n";
}
else{
    print  "CustomerDomain=\"COM\"
        />
        </Org>
        \n";
}
```

All work fine except when I compare against "Veteran's Affairs" which causes the if condition to fail.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hash doesn't have a `"Veteran's Affairs"` key, it has a `"Veteran's Affairs"` *value*. If you defined your hash in the more common fashion:

```
my %cot_descn = (
    "Correctional" => "Veteran's Affairs",
    "State Pharmacy Assistance Program" => "VA Medical Center",
    "VA Mail Order Pharmacy" => "PHS 340B Entity"
);
```

then the structure would be clearer. Since there is no `"Veteran's Affairs"` key, of course this test will send you into the `else` branch:

```
if (exists $cot_descn{$var_cot_descn})
```

when `$var_cot_descn` is `"Veteran's Affairs"`.

Perhaps you have the first key/value in your `%cot_descn` backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------
use Data::Dumper;

# Make Data::Dumper pretty
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;

# Set maximum depth for Data::Dumper, zero means unlimited
local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 0;

# --------------------------------------

my @cot_descn = (
        "Correctional",
        "Veteran's Affairs",
        "State Pharmacy Assistance Program",
        "VA Medical Center",
        "VA Mail Order Pharmacy",
        "PHS 340B Entity",
    );
my %cot_descn = map { $_ => 1 } @cot_descn;

print Dumper \%cot_descn;
```